# How to convert timestamp to the number of days

Tags: mysql

Supposing I have a timestamp 123456. How to convert to the number of days (day count). **For example: if 123 -> 1 days, then 122 -> 0 day.**

My query has this:
something_to_get_the_number_of_day(TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - TIMESTAMP('2011-12-13 14:00:00'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DATEDIFF() function which will give you the difference in days.

You can use something like:

```
DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(NOW()), TIMESTAMP('2011-12-13 14:00:00')) AS DiffDate
```

That should give you the result you want.

[Here's a w3schools link on the DATEDIFF() function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)

Edit: From your comment, I now see you want to include the actual time too.

You should be able to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` instead then (providing you are using mySQL 5.0.0+)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: DATEDIFF calculation doesn't include time (hour, minute and second). I want to get the number of day of a timestamp. See my example above.